# How to handle multiple threads efficiently / only perform a load operation once for all queued up load calls?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, reentrantlock

I'm attempting to write java code that executes a load operation as described below.

**Initial Call (Thread One):**
Initiates a loading process and immediately returns.

**Second Call (Thread Two):**

If Thread One is in the midst of loading, it waits.
Once Thread One finishes, Thread Two starts its own load.
After its load is done, it returns.

**Subsequent Calls (Thread Three and beyond):**
If Thread One is loading, it waits.
Does not queue behind both Thread One and Thread Two.
Instead, it leverages the load process initiated by Thread Two.
Returns in tandem with Thread Two once the loading is completed.

The load method is called from an api-controller method.

My current implementation is not good because the same thread is handling the flush for the next threads, while it should have returned. If the method is invoked multiple times and the isLoadPending flag is set, the same thread continually handles the load, potentially without ever releasing. Ideally, after waiting for a prior load to finish, a thread should only need to flush at most one more time.

```
private final ReentrantLock loadLock = new ReentrantLock();
private final AtomicBoolean isLoadPending = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public void loadAll() {
    if (loadLock.tryLock()) {
        try {
            DbLoadService.load();
            while (isLoadPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                DbLoadService.load();
            }
        } finally {
            loadLock.unlock();
        }
    } else {
        isLoadPending.set(true);
        loadLock.lock();
        loadLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Whatever you believe, this sequence `loadLock.lock(); loadLock.unlock();` does: no, it doesn’t. It’s pointless. Further, there is a contradiction in thread one “*Initiates a loading process and immediately returns*” and thread two’s condition “*If Thread One is in the midst of loading*”. How can thread one be “in the midst of loading” when it doesn’t load but only “Initiates a loading process” and “*immediately returns*”?

Comment: Is there an actual question? I think you need to focus more and ask something about a specific question.  "Suggestions", "not good", "ideally" -- these aren't specific, just requests for free form discussion and tentative code changes.  Try to focus on one thing specifically that is definitely a problem, show us how to produce the problem and then we might be able to say something concrete about the code.

Comment: I'm also concerned about this sequence: `DbLoadService.load(); while (isLoadPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {          DbLoadService.load();` which looks a lot like busy waiting while holding a lock.  Seems like it might be counter-productive.

Comment: @Holger the  loadLock.lock(); loadLock.unlock(); sequence functions as a wait as  loadLock.lock(); is blocking, ensuring the thread does not return before the load is completed. My wording for the initial call could have been better, the load should complete before it returns.

Comment: @markspace Apologies for the vagueness. My primary concern is preventing a thread from being stuck in continuous loading when isLoadPending is set. How can I modify the code to ensure threads behave as described in the initial post, particularly for Thread 3's desired behavior?

Comment: You seem to think that lock actions have to progress in the order of the `lock()` calls but that’s not the case. Even if you change the code to use a fair lock, `tryLock` still may overtake any waiting thread, and perform the unconditional first `DbLoadService.load();` before even checking the flag. In other words, the availability of a `Lock` should not be confused with a `Condition`. Though, your task looks more like a `Phaser`’s job anyway.

Comment: @markspace The check is needed in case a load was called after the last one began.

Comment: @Holger Ok, thanks. I was not aware of that. Il take a look at Phaser and attempt another implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you want something like this:

```java
final Phaser loadPhaser = new Phaser() {
    protected boolean onAdvance(int phase, int registeredParties) {
        DbLoadService.load();
        return false;
    }
};

public void loadAll() {
    int myPhase = loadPhaser.register();
    loadPhaser.arriveAndDeregister();
    loadPhaser.awaitAdvance(myPhase);
}
```

In this specific use case, the threads belonging to a particular phase are the threads entering `loadAll()` at the same time or while a previous `DbLoadService.load()` is in progress. Since this is different for each phase, they have to register and unregister each time.

All threads calling `register()` while a previous `DbLoadService.load()` is in progress will wait for its completion, then all of them will call `arriveAndDeregister()` and the last one will perform the new `DbLoadService.load()` operation. The others will wait for the completion of this new `DbLoadService.load()` operation in `awaitAdvance`.

New threads arriving at `register()` are clearly distinct from the threads waiting at `awaitAdvance` at the same time—they belong to a different phase. In fact, when this overlapping happens, it is impossible for the thread performing the current `load()` to become part of the next phase, so it’s impossible for a thread to get stuck in repeatedly performing the `load` operation.

Comment: This is a great solution, looks clean, tested it now and it works perfectly. Much appreciated. And thank you for introducing me to Phaser!